# Set default DateRange for DatePicker + JQuery + PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-range

I am using JQuery DatePicker to set a "Date Range" .As you can see below, I have used a single field for the Datepicker. Now, my requirement is to set the Default date range into the Datepicker on page load. The dates should be today's date and 7 days AGO date.

```
<div id="date-range-field">
<span id="dateranger"></span> //should hold like this value : "7 January, 2015 - 14 January, 2015" bydefault on page load
<a href="#">&#9660;</a>
</div>
<div id="datepicker-calendar"></div>

$('#datepicker-calendar').DatePicker({mode: 'range'});
```

Thanks

Comment: use min-date and max-date

Comment: @MarcoMura : i have tried with that ,, but no success . I am facing problem as I am using RANGE mode of datepicker and not being able to find out a way how to insert dates in a range. It would be great if u provide a code snippet which would be useful

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?Php
$today=date('Y-m-d');
$time = strtotime($today.' -7 days');
$day7 = date("Y-m-d", $time);

   echo '<input type="date" min="'.$day7.'" max="'.$today.'">';

?>
```

it would be probably something like this

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 $(function() {
      $('#datepicker-calendar').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('#datepicker-calendar').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date); // Reset minimum date
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7); // Subtract7 days
            $('#datepicker-calendar').datepicker('setDate', date); // Set as default

      }});
      $('#datepicker-calendar').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {

            $('#datepicker-calendar').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate')); // Reset maximum date

      }});
});
```